# How to close a node.js program with express in vue?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

I work with express and vue3 I have found multiple solutions but they all do not seem to work because of vue

I have something like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="exit"></button>
  </div>
</template>
```

and I just want to close the application with this.

```
<script>
function exit() {
    process.exit(1)
}
</script>
```

Comment: the javascript in this `<script>` tag is ran on the browser, there is no `process` object. It is unclear what you are wanting? are you wanting to close the browser tab window?

Comment: Would something like this work? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vuejs/vuejs_instances.htm

Comment: Normally you need to send a request from frontend to backend (nodejs) in order to do backend operations like closing a nodejs program!

Comment: Consider explaining your case. This could be XY problem.